# Spark stream to reset the mapWithState daily

Tags: spark-streaming

I am counting daily number of unique users logged into system.Data is fed to spark through kafka.We maintain counts using the mapwithstate functionality.Every 10 seconds computed data is sent to kafka.I need to reset these numbers daily at midnight.
Is there any way to clear all the data from the "mapwithState" variable ?

```
 public class UserCounts {


 private static JavaStreamingContext createContext(String[] args) {

    String brokers = args[1];
    String inputTopic = args[2];
    String outputTopic = args[3];
    String masterNode = args[4];

    HashMap<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    // Create the context with a 3 second batch size
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("UserCounts").setMaster(masterNode);
    //sparkConf.set("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1");


    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(10));

    Set<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(inputTopic.split(",")));
    Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", brokers);
    ssc.checkpoint(".");


    // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and inputTopic
    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            ssc,
            String.class,
            String.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            kafkaParams,
            topicsSet
    );
    JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(Tuple2::_2);
    JavaDStream<String> userIds = lines.map(x -> {
        String array[] = x.split(",");
        return array[3];
    });

    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> usersDstream = userIds.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1));

    // Update the cumulative count function
    Function3<String, Optional<Integer>, State<Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>> mappingFunc =
            (userId, one, state) -> {
                int sum = one.orElse(0) + (state.exists() ? state.get() : 0);
                Tuple2<String, Integer> output = new Tuple2<>(userId, sum);
                state.update(sum);
                return output;
            };

    // DStream made of get cumulative counts that get updated in every batch
    JavaMapWithStateDStream<String, Integer, Integer, Tuple2<String, Integer>> stateDstream =
            usersDstream.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(mappingFunc));

    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> stateSnapshotStream = stateDstream.stateSnapshots();



    stateSnapshotStream.count().foreachRDD(rdd -> {

        System.out.println("# events = " + rdd.count());
        String date = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

        rdd.foreachPartition(partition -> {
                    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer(props);
                    while (partition.hasNext()) {
                        Long value = partition.next();
                        System.out.println("data >>>>>>>>>>" + value.toString());
                        String data = "{\"timestamp\":\"" + date + "\",\"usersCount\":\"" + value.toString() + "\"}";
                        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(outputTopic, null, data));
                    }
                    producer.close();

                }
        );


    });



    return ssc;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String checkpointPath = args[0];

    Function0<JavaStreamingContext> createContextFunc = () -> createContext(args);

    JavaStreamingContext ssc =
            JavaStreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointPath, createContextFunc);

    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();

  }
}
```

Comment: `mapWithState` isn't the way to go here. You need to be able to touch all keys every batch to be able to reset them at 00:00. You'll need to use `updateStateByKey` for that.

Comment: Can you please share some code sample as I am not getting how i will trigger updatestate at 00:00?

Comment: It won't trigger an update state at `00:00`, it will trigger `updateStateByKey` at every batch interval you define. You, yourself, will need to check the current time and reset that state for all keys.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Can you please review my solution?I have just have conern about the date object created in filter.Is there any better solution to that.Thanks in advance ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used mapWithState by modifying the keys with userid+date.And added a timeout of 24 hours.And filtered data of snapshot with current date. Please let me if this solution can be improved.The date object i am creating in filter is one of the concern right now i have.

```
public class UserCounts {


private static JavaStreamingContext createContext(String[] args) {

    String brokers = args[1];
    String inputTopic = args[2];
    String outputTopic = args[3];
    String masterNode = args[4];
    SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    HashMap<String, String> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
            "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

    // Create the context with a 3 second batch size
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("UserCounts").setMaster(masterNode);
    //sparkConf.set("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1");


    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(10));

    Set<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(inputTopic.split(",")));
    Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", brokers);
    ssc.checkpoint(".");


    // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and inputTopic
    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
            ssc,
            String.class,
            String.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            StringDecoder.class,
            kafkaParams,
            topicsSet
    );
    JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(Tuple2::_2);
   //userId can be duplicated in multiple days,so appended date with it and filtered in snapshot.Keys will be removed by timeout function of mapwithstate after 24 hours
    JavaDStream<String> userIds = lines.map(x -> {
        String array[] = x.split(",");
        String userId = array[3];
        String timestamp = array[11];

        return userId+"-"+timestamp.substring(0,10);
    });

    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> usersDstream = userIds.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1));

    // Update the cumulative count function
    Function3<String, Optional<Integer>, State<Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>> mappingFunc =
            (userId, one, state) -> {
                int sum = one.orElse(0) + (state.exists() ? state.get() : 0);
                Tuple2<String, Integer> output = new Tuple2<>(userId, sum);
                state.update(sum);
                return output;
            };

    // DStream made of get cumulative counts that get updated in every batch 
    //Timout of 24 hours will make sure the keys which are generated will be removed 
    JavaMapWithStateDStream<String, Integer, Integer, Tuple2<String, Integer>> stateDstream =
            usersDstream.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(mappingFunc).timeout(Durations.seconds(86400)));

    JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> stateSnapshotStream = stateDstream.stateSnapshots();



    stateSnapshotStream.filter(x-> {
        //create date object to get current date,can't be intialized class level or method level as it should change every day
        Date date = new Date();
        String currentDate = format.format(date);

        if(x._1.endsWith(currentDate)) {
            return true;
        }else  {
            return false;
        }

    }).count().foreachRDD(rdd -> {

        System.out.println("# events = " + rdd.count());
        String date = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

        rdd.foreachPartition(partition -> {
                    KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer(props);
                    while (partition.hasNext()) {
                        Long value = partition.next();
                        System.out.println("data >>>>>>>>>>" + value.toString());
                        String data = "{\"timestamp\":\"" + date + "\",\"usersCount\":\"" + value.toString() + "\"}";
                        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(outputTopic, null, data));
                    }
                    producer.close();

                }
        );


    });



    return ssc;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String checkpointPath = args[0];

    Function0<JavaStreamingContext> createContextFunc = () -> createContext(args);

    JavaStreamingContext ssc =
            JavaStreamingContext.getOrCreate(checkpointPath, createContextFunc);

    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can store time information in the `State` and easily reset the count.